# Android:Problem with sending Data Sms

Tags: android

I have written code to send encrypted message.
But the encrypted data SMS  is not delivering because onrecive() methode is not invoking . I think I have problem in receiver part.

Now, I am new in android.. Any body help me what is the wrong with the following code (I am using RSA algo)? Thanks in advance........

For Sending:

```
public class MainMethod extends Activity 
{
    Button btnSendSMS;
    EditText txtPhoneNo;
    EditText txtMessage;
    Button stop ;
    static boolean bombing = false;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);        
        btnSendSMS = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSendSMS);
        txtPhoneNo = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtPhoneNo);
        txtMessage = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtMessage);

        btnSendSMS.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() 
        {
            public void onClick(View v) 
            {
                try{
                   KeyGenerator keyGen = KeyGenerator.getInstance("HmacMD5");
                    SecretKey MD5key = keyGen.generateKey();
                    FileOutputStream fos = openFileOutput( "MD5key.txt" ,Context.MODE_WORLD_READABLE);
                    fos.write(MD5key.getEncoded());
                }
                catch(Exception e) {
                    ;
                }
                    String phoneNo = txtPhoneNo.getText().toString();
                    String message = txtMessage.getText().toString();
                    if (phoneNo.length()>0 && message.length()>0)
                    {
                        try{
                        stop = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnSendSMS);
                        BigInteger ptext = new BigInteger(message.getBytes());  
                        BigInteger ciphertext = encrypt(ptext);
                        message = ciphertext.toString();
                        stop.setText("Message Sent");
                            SMSbomb(phoneNo,message  );
                        }
                        catch(Exception e) {
                            ;
                        }
                        }
                    else
                    {
                         stop = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnSendSMS);
                        stop.setText("Send Properly");
                        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Please enter both phone number and message.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }

            }
        });        
    }


    private void SMSbomb(String phoneNumber, String message)
{
        String SENT = "SMS_SENT";
        String DELIVERED = "SMS_DELIVERED";
        PendingIntent sentPI = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, new Intent(SENT), 0);
        PendingIntent deliveredPI = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, new Intent(DELIVERED), 0);
        registerReceiver(new BroadcastReceiver(){
            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) 
            {

                switch (getResultCode())
                {   
                    case Activity.RESULT_OK:
                        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "SMS sent", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        stop.setText("Proceeding");
                        break;

                    case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_GENERIC_FAILURE:
                        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Generic failure", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        MainMethod.endBombing();
                        break;
                    case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_NO_SERVICE:
                        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "No service", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        MainMethod.endBombing();
                        break;
                    case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_NULL_PDU:
                        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Null PDU", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        MainMethod.endBombing();
                        break;
                    case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_RADIO_OFF:
                        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Radio off", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        MainMethod.endBombing();
                        break;
                }
            }
        }, new IntentFilter(SENT));

        registerReceiver(new BroadcastReceiver(){
            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent arg1) {
                switch (getResultCode())
                {
                    case Activity.RESULT_OK:
                        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "SMS delivered", 
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        stop.setText("Send Message");
                        break;
                    case Activity.RESULT_CANCELED:
                        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "SMS not delivered", 
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        break;                        
                }
            }
        }, new IntentFilter(DELIVERED));        

        SmsManager sms = SmsManager.getDefault();
        sms.sendDataMessage(phoneNumber , null, (short) 3492, message.getBytes(), sentPI, deliveredPI);
        stop.setText("Send Message");
    }
    public static void endBombing()
    {
        bombing = false;
    }
    public static synchronized String encrypt(String message) {
        BigInteger e = new BigInteger("e") ;
          BigInteger n = new BigInteger(n");
        return (new BigInteger(message.getBytes())).modPow(e, n).toString();
      }

      public static synchronized BigInteger encrypt(BigInteger message) {
          BigInteger e = new BigInteger("e") ;
          BigInteger n = new BigInteger("n");
        return message.modPow(e, n);
      }
    }
```

//////////

For Receiving:

public class SmsReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver
{

```
private static final String TAG = "MySmsReceiver";


public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) 
{
    Log.i(TAG, "Recieved a message");

    String ds = "" ;
    //---get the SMS message passed in---
     Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
        if (bundle != null) {
            Object[] pdusObj = (Object[]) bundle.get("pdus");
            SmsMessage[] messages = new SmsMessage[pdusObj.length];

            // getting SMS information from PDU
            for (int i = 0; i < pdusObj.length; i++) {
                messages[i] = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[]) pdusObj[i]);
            }

            for (SmsMessage currentMessage : messages) {
                if (!currentMessage.isStatusReportMessage()) {
 String messageBody = currentMessage.getDisplayMessageBody();

                        byte[] messageByteArray = currentMessage.getPdu();

                        // skipping PDU header, keeping only message body
                        int x = 1 + messageByteArray[0] + 19 + 7;

                        String str = new String(messageByteArray, x, messageByteArray.length-x);
                        ds = currentMessage.getOriginatingAddress() ;

        //---display the new SMS message---
        String plaintext = decrypt(str);
    String plaintext1 = "SMS from " + ds + " Message " + plaintext ;


       Toast t =  Toast.makeText(context, plaintext1, Toast.LENGTH_LONG);  
       t.setDuration(30);
       t.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL, 50, 50);
       t.show();
                }
            }

    }                         
}
```

//Here e and n are RSA's shared secret.
        public static synchronized String decrypt(String message) {
            String ds = "e" ;
            String ns = "n" ;
            BigInteger d = new BigInteger(ds) ;
            BigInteger n = new BigInteger(ns) ;
            return new String((new BigInteger(message)).modPow(d, n).toByteArray());
          }

```
      public static synchronized BigInteger decrypt(BigInteger message) {
          String ds = "e" ;
        String ns = "n" ;
         BigInteger d = new BigInteger(ds) ;
         BigInteger n = new BigInteger(ns) ;
        return message.modPow(d, n);
      } 

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only need to register your receiver once. 
Register the receivers that you have in  `SMSbomb(phoneNo,message  );` in `onCreate()` instead.
I hope that helps!