# Problem with sending bulk data message in Android 

Tags: android

I am able to write code that can send a sort data message using `SMSManager.sendDataMessage`. However, I don't know why it is not working with bulk data message (which contains approx. 200 chars). Can anybody can help me with this?

Comment: Text messages are limited to 160 characters. That's just how it was designed: http://latimesblogs.latimes.com/technology/2009/05/invented-text-messaging.html

Comment: Ok I got it..... But, is there any method to send it in android means suppose 200 characters ???????

Comment: I'd use push notifications instead. See this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1243066/does-android-support-near-real-time-push-notification

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you could post a more specific question and a code block where you think your program fails perhaps I could help, after looking at the API as well it seems as if this function is deprecated, it suggests using `android.telephony.SmsManager` instead, hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for reply.... You can find the code here, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6318689/androidproblem-with-sending-data-sms